# PHP 7.0 is showing function declaration in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was using php 5.6 then my code was working fine but when I am using php7.0 + then the same code is showing

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Declaration of MX_Lang::load($langfile, $lang = '', $return = false, $add_suffix = true, $alt_path = '', $_module = '') should be compatible with CI_Lang::load($langfile = '', $idiom = '', $return = false, $add_suffix = true, $alt_path = '')

Filename: MX/Lang.php
```

Comment: What is the line number, where you are getting the error?

Comment: You can find answer here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840941/codeigniter-hmvc-error-after-updating-php-to-php-7

Answer (score 0):

Do the the following changes

```
third_party\MX\Lang.php
 line=70
 public function load($langfile ='', $lang = '', $return = FALSE, $add_suffix = TRUE, $alt_path = '', $_module = '')
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.